# python3 code to retrieve just one particular line from webpage source code

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, urlopen

In my code I'm using urlopen but it fetches whole webpage.Is it possible to retrieve just one particular line number of the webpage source code so as to optimize my program

say for eg I want to print line number 135 from the source code of this link `www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=273898673?term=273898673`

**mycode:**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
query="www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=273898673?term=273898673"
data=urlopen(query)
html = data.read()
codec = data.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
data = html.decode(codec)
print (data)
```

is there any urlopen() customization i can carry out ?
**P.S** i have python 3.X

Comment: No, it is not possible. The web server will always serve the entire document so you will have to parse the acquired text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate to get the specific line number without reading everything in memory at once:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/snp/?term=273898673?term=273898673')
for line_number, line in enumerate(response):
    # Because this is 0-index based
    if line_number == 134:
        print line
    # Stop reading
    elif line_number > 134:
        break
```